# Ember data: When to autocommit changes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing an Ember application that lets the user modifies data and auto-commits changes to the backend without having to click any "Save" button. I'm facing a weird issue when in this code

```
record.set(key, newValue);
record.get('store').commit();
```

the `commit()` method gets called first before the record is added to the `updated` bucket. If I delay `commit()`

```
record.set(key, newValue);
setTimeout(function() {
  record.get('store').commit();
}, 1);
```

it works perfectly fine but doesn't feel like a proper way to do things in Ember. Is there any event that notifies when the record is ready to be saved?

Comment: How do you know that the data isn't saved. Do You make record.set('foo', 'bar'); record.get('store').commit(); and record.get('foo'); returns undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it works perfectly fine but doesn't feel like a proper way to do things in Ember. Is there any event that notifies when the record is ready to be saved?

There is a flag you could setup an observer on, this is the `isDirty` property that indicates the record has local changes which are still not commited, example:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  isDirtyChanged: function() {
    if(this.get('isDirty')) {
      this.get('store').commit();
    }
  }.observes('isDirty')
});
```

Then after calling:

```
record.set(key, newValue);
```

the `isDirtyChanged` is invoked automatically because of the observer we have setup validating the `isDirty` property and committing if is it true.

You can also check here for more lifecycle events and properties: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/

See also here for a [demo](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/107/edit) (it has some other stuff, but please focus only on the `Author` model and how the observer is setup, also on the `PostController` and the `update` function in it) enter something in the input field below the Author name and press the `Update` button, now watch the console logs.

Hope it helps.